# What explains this really bizarre nil error when using an API I created on API Gateway

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, runtime-error, aws-api-gateway

I've created a simple API in Swift 3 using the Gateway API. In `APPNAMEClient.swift` I have the following AWS code:

```
 self.configuration.endpoint = AWSEndpoint(region: configuration.regionType, service: .apiGateway, url: URL(string: URLString))
```

Which results in the following error message:

```
2017-05-28 01:49:21.526026 AWSPLEASE[6704:13258772] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What does this mean? The code before the `nil` error message looks meaningless.

Comment: This error occurs if `URLString` string is not a valid URL and the parameter `url` expects a non-optional value.

Comment: Interesting  @vadian the URL is just hardcoded to the api gateway end point. Should I change this to something? Why would the api gateway's endpoint url be invalid?

Comment: It's just a general explanation in which case this line of code can cause an `unexpectedly found nil` error. Your information is too little to be more specific.